# Twilio: responding to incoming SMS message

Tags: sms, twilio

After I send a sms message to a particular phone number, how do I track the potential conversation? 
I see that there is the URL within my Twilio account that Twilio sends http requests to.
Do I just keep checking this URL and go through the messages from the user, using the "from" field in the JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When someone responds to your Twilio number then that URL you set in your account will receive a POST or GET request (your choice) with all the details of the message. You don't need to check that URL, the information will come to you.

You could then use the [REST API to gather the messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list) that have gone back and forth between your app by calling for all the messages sent to the user's number and all the messages received from the users number.

You can also, in response to an incoming SMS message, set cookies that can be retrieved as part of the HTTP request. So, if you want to save some data between messages that's a way to achieve that. Here's a [guide on using cookies to track SMS conversations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/tracking-conversations).